# Derivative of $(\sin x + \cos x)\sec x$

Tags: calculus

I need to find the derivative of $(\sin x + \cos x)\sec x$. I simplified it to

$$\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\cos x}$$

Can someone explain the steps very throughly? I am struggling with derivatives involving trig functions.  I can't seem to grasp the concept of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is similar to the problem I sometimes ask calculus I: differentiate $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)$. I fish in many.

Comment: Are you just struggling with derivatives involving trig functions, rules of differentiation, or just derivatives in general?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook "That's an easy one. $2 \cos x (-\sin x) + 2 \sin x \cos x = 0$" is what I imagine a lot of people say?

Comment: I'm struggling with rules of differentiation involving trig functions

Comment: @user92774 in fact, that is not unusual, for some reason students tend to think showing more work means they get more credit. I can't blame them, I suffered under the same delusion in my younger years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases it's helpful to get rid of the parentheses. Distribute the $\sec x$:

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \frac{\cos x}{\cos x}$$

$$= \tan x + 1$$

You know what to do from here.